# Subquery (and query with join) not using index with MySQL (MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, subquery

I am trying to find out why this query is quite slow on a very big DB (40M+ rows).
The problem seems to be with the "WHERE users_fb_table.`installed` = 1" clause.

```
SELECT users_fb_table.`id_user_fb`, `id_fb`, `first_name`
FROM (
    SELECT `id_user`, `id_user_fb`
    FROM friends_table
    WHERE friends_table.`id_user` = 10
) AS temp
JOIN users_fb_table ON temp.`id_user_fb` = users_fb_table.`id_user_fb`
WHERE users_fb_table.`installed` = 1
```

I have tryed not to use the subquery, but the result is the same. The following query returns the same result set (30 rows), and the execution time is exactly the same:

```
SELECT friends_table.`id_user_fb`, `id_fb`, `first_name`
FROM friends_table
JOIN users_fb_table ON friends_table.`id_user_fb` = users_fb_table.`id_user_fb`
WHERE friends_table.`id_user` = 10 and users_fb_table.`installed` = 1
```

The following query is instead very fast:

```
SELECT friends_table.`id_user_fb`, `id_fb`, `first_name`
FROM friends_table
JOIN users_fb_table ON friends_table.`id_user_fb` = users_fb_table.`id_user_fb`
WHERE friends_table.`id_user` = 10 limit 30
```

This one is also very fast:

```
SELECT`id_user_fb`, `id_fb`, `first_name`
FROM users_fb_table
WHERE users_fb_table.`installed` = 1 limit 30
```

The create statemens for the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_fb_table` (
  `id_user_fb` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_fb` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `gender` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` char(128) NOT NULL,
  `locale` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `installed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `email` char(128) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user_fb`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_fb` (`id_fb`),
  KEY `installed` (`installed`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends_table` (
  `id_friend` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_user_fb` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_friend`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_index` (`id_user`,`id_user_fb`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `id_user_fb` (`id_user_fb`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What can I do to make the execution faster?
I was trying to create a subquery with index but without success.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How many records do you have for each user, regardless of the installed flag?  Can you quantity "slow" and "fast"?

Comment: It depensd on the user, it varies can be 100 and up to thousands. I have tested the query on low load situation and a slow query takes 0.03 seconds (may be not too much, but on high load it can take seconds). While with fast I mean 0.0002 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are not comparable.  The last two that run "fast" use a `limit` clause.  Your query does not.  Try adding a `limit 30` to your query to see if it runs faster.  It might not, because the query may have to go through more than 30 records to find 30 that meet the installed condition.

The use of `limit` suggests that there are a lot of rows for each user that match in the `fb` table.  If so, try this index:  `users_fb_table(id_user_fb, installed)`.  This index can be used for both the `join` and the `where` condition.

Actually, an even better index is  `users_fb_table(id_user_fb, installed, id_fb, first_name)`.  This query "covers" the query so the execution engine can satisfy the query only with the index, not having to refer to the data pages.

Comment: In fact limit 30 on the first query takes the same time, a lower limit makes it faster. I will try to add the index as you suggest.